# metadata_startup_script is not installing sql server proxy inside the VM instance GCP using Terraform script

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, terraform, metadata, terraform-provider-gcp

The below metadata_startup_script is not creating sql server proxy.
I have noticed that `sudo wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64`
this command is not getting executed. I could see that wget is installed.

```
  metadata_startup_script = <<SCRIPT
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
    sudo apt-get -y update
    sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
    echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
    echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc
    sudo apt-get -y install wget
    sudo wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64
    sudo mv cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 cloud_sql_proxy
    sudo chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
    SCRIPT
```

I would like to know error involved in metadata_startup_script.
I am pasting the startup script logs.

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2022-03-01 18:27:04 UTC, end at Wed 2022-03-02 01:11:06 UTC. --
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: Starting startup scripts (version 20211116.00).
-- Logs begin at Tue 2022-03-01 18:27:04 UTC, end at Wed 2022-03-02 01:11:06 UTC. --
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: Starting startup scripts (version 20211116.00).
-- Logs begin at Tue 2022-03-01 18:27:04 UTC, end at Wed 2022-03-02 01:11:06 UTC. --
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: Starting startup scripts (version 20211116.00).
-- Logs begin at Tue 2022-03-01 18:27:04 UTC, end at Wed 2022-03-02 01:11:06 UTC. --
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: Starting startup scripts (version 20211116.00).
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: Found startup-script in metadata.
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 sudo[507]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-key add -
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 sudo[507]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: [174B blob data]
Mar 01 18:27:08 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: OK
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 sudo[507]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: 2022/03/01 18:27:09 logging client: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: metadata: GCE metadata "instance/service-a
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 sudo[969]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 sudo[969]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: [174B blob data]
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 sudo[969]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 sudo[972]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get -y update
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 sudo[972]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:09 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease [46.7 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:5 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-buster InRelease [6780 B]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-buster InRelease [5553 B]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease [10.5 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [223 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:9 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-buster-stable InRelease [5526 B]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [317 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en [171 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources.diff/Index [10.1 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [10.1 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en.diff/Index [6148 B]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources 2022-01-24-2024.03.pdiff [257 B]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources 2022-01-24-2024.03.pdiff [257 B]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: 2022/03/01 18:27:10 logging client: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: metadata: GCE metadata "instance/service-a
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:16 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-buster/main amd64 Packages [225 kB]
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:17 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-buster/main amd64 Packages [390 
Mar 01 18:27:10 terraform-instance12 google_metadata_script_runner[470]: startup-script: Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages 2022-01-24-2024.03.pdiff [1124 B]
```

Comment: what is in the startup script logs? ssh into the vm and run `sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service` then edit the post and add the output (remove any sensitive data). Alternatively, see [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output) to access logs using serial ports.

Comment: What's the output from `cat /etc/os-release` on the VM? Are you sure it's Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the instances are installed.
But they are in the different folder or in a different path. We can find them in linux using the command "readlink -f filename".
And can get them in the desired folder.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to me. It probably should have been a comment on the question.